# C# TCP asynchronous sending multiple files from server to client do we need any acknowledgement?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asynchronous, tcp

my code is use to send multiple files from server to client:

Server:

```
    public void SendFiles(string filePath)
    {
        try
        {
            Debug.WriteImportant("SendFiles() - " + filePath);
            byte[] fileBuff = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            byte[] fileSize = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileBuff.Length);
            byte[] dir = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)) + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
            byte[] fileHeader = new byte[fileSize.Length + dir.Length];

            fileSize.CopyTo(fileHeader, 0);
            dir.CopyTo(fileHeader, fileSize.Length);

            Send(fileHeader);
            Send(fileBuff);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteImportant(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    public void Send(byte[] byteData)
    {
        try
        {
            // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
            pMySocket.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), pMySocket);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteImportant(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
            Debug.WriteImportant("Sent" + bytesSent + "bytes to client @." + strConstID);

            pMySocket.BeginReceive(byRxBuffer, 0, byRxBuffer.Length, 0, ReceiveCallback, pMySocket);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteImportant(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Client:

```
        private static void Receive(Socket client)
    {
        try
        {
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = client;

            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveHeaderCallback), state);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static void ReceiveHeaderCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("## Begin ReceiveHeaderCallback");
            String content = String.Empty;
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = state.workSocket;

            int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

            state.fileSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(state.buffer, 0);
            byte[] bFileName = new byte[state.buffer.Length - 4];
            Array.Copy(state.buffer, 4, bFileName, 0, bFileName.Length);
            _Buff = new byte[state.fileSize];
            fileName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bFileName).TrimEnd('\0'); 
            _totBytesRead = 0;
            Debug.WriteLine("## File size = " + state.fileSize);
            Debug.WriteLine("## File name = " + fileName);

            Array.Clear(state.buffer, 0, state.buffer.Length);
            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
               new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            String content = String.Empty;
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = state.workSocket;

            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
                Buffer.BlockCopy(state.buffer, 0, _Buff, _totBytesRead, bytesRead);

                _totBytesRead += bytesRead;

                if (_totBytesRead < state.fileSize)
                {
                    // Not all data received. Get more.
                    client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
                }
                else
                {                            File.WriteAllBytes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + fileName, _Buff);
                    Debug.WriteLine("## File receiving complete. File created = " + fileName);

                    Array.Clear(state.buffer, 0, state.buffer.Length);
                    client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveHeaderCallback), state);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

The problem I face now is when I send multiple files at the same time, there will be problem occur in client side. It can't receive the file correctly.

May I ask does the client need to do some kind of acknowledgement telling the server that it had complete receive a file and you can send another file?

Or is it we can somehow flush or close the sending stream after sending a file and open it again when send another file?

What is need to be added to my coding?

Comment: The proper way of sending the file is to include a byte count at beginning of each file.  Then the server can remove the byte count and read the entire number of bytes to determine then end of each file.  It would also be useful to send the filename after the byte count.

Comment: Yes.. I have done it already.. The problem is on the Buffer.BlockCopy(). If I have multiple files, bytesRead will always be full. When last block of data, Buffer.BlockCopy() produce error

Comment: The last block the buffer is not full.  You are always copying the entire buffer size : bFileName.Length

Comment: But for mine, the bytes from the second file will contain in the last block of the first file. Making Buffer.BlockCopy() produce error

Comment: The just copy the number of bytes from last file.  You know the issue now fix the code.